# Read only certain columns (read permissions) of a PostGIS database in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, pgadmin

In our administration, each employee is given various rights to read and edit data on the PostgreSQL/PostGIS database. To view the geodata, we use QGIS. In this case there should be read permissions on only 3 columns. The rest should not be seen by the user.
In PgAdmin I have distributed the permissions as follows:

```
GRANT SELECT(name) ON test.krankenhaus_test TO r_test;
GRANT SELECT(geom) ON test.krankenhaus_test TO r_test;
GRANT SELECT(krankenhaus_id) ON test.krankenhaus_test TO r_test;
```

Unfortunately I cannot see this table in QGIS. We use PostgreSQL 13.7 and QGIS 3.22.10. When I assign a grant select to the full table, I get the complete table displayed in QGIS.

```
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE test.krankenhaus_test TO r_test;
```

However, as I said, I only want to be able to see the three columns.

Comment: Use a view on just the permitted columns

Comment: View feels like a good option. But if you turn on the SQL statement logging in PostgreSQL you can see the queries that QGIS is sending and then you can consider what other rights you should give for your users.

Comment: Did you try unchecking the `only show tables with geometry` box?

Comment: Make sure you add the layer via query from the DB Manager and not directly from Layer>Add PostGIS Layer

Comment: It actually worked via the DB Manager. So this seems to be a QGIS bug?